# How to return an array of values in output parameter in Stored Proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, isnull

I have a situation to send the IDs that has status Inactive through the stored proc. Also, in the same SP, once I send the inactive IDs, I need to update it to active. So I am doing it in transaction. But don't know how to send sets of IDs and also if my update is correct or not. I think I need to loop for update? Please help me with the construct.

```
Create Proc Name
@ID VARCHAR INT OUT
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRAN
SELECT @ID = ID From MyTable
WHERE IDType = 1 AND B ='Rev'

Update MyTable
Set IDType = 2
WHERE IDType = 1 AND B='Rev'
COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Comment: You can't do this using `OUTPUT` parameter. The best way is to use a `SELECT` statement in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `OUTPUT` parameter, you could do a `SELECT` inside your stored procedure using the `OUTPUT` and `INTO` clause. Here is an example:

Let's create our test data:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    ID  INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    IDType  INT,
    B   VARCHAR(6)
)
INSERT INTO MyTable(IDType, B) VALUES
(2, 'Rev'), (2, 'Rev'),
(2, 'Rev'), (1, 'Rev'),
(1, 'Rev'), (1, 'Rev'),
(1, 'NotRev'), (1, 'NotRev');
```

MyTable:

```
ID          IDType      B
----------- ----------- ------
1           2           Rev
2           2           Rev
3           2           Rev
4           1           Rev
5           1           Rev
6           1           Rev
7           1           NotRev
8           1           NotRev
```

What we want is to update rows `WHERE IDType = 2 AND B = 'Rev'`. In this case, the rows to be updated are `ID IN(4, 5, 6)`.

Now create your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProc
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE MyTable
        SET IDType = 2
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID -- Returns the IDs of the updated rows
    WHERE 
        IDType = 1
        AND B = 'REV'

END
```

To get the updated rows, you use the `OUTPUT` clause.

Executing your stored procedure will return:

```
ID
-----------
4
5
6
```

Comment: You don't need temp table. Just `OUTPUT` without `INTO`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan: Buddy thank you so much for being so nice and helping me, I am at home, its 11.02 PM. Tomorrow morning I need to go to work at 7.30 AM and need to complete it. I will use your idea an see how it goes. I will surely reply here tomorrow :) I dont have access to code out of office as I work in Bank :) Cheers

Comment: @FelixPamittan: Thanks, although it serves the purpose, my lead told me that, what if some failure or some error happens before it sends the updated status ID to Service. In that case, already my update also would have happened which is not correct. So, it is only after ensuring that the update is sent to service and some kind of acknowledgement is received, I should set the status :( I don't know how to do it. But I reckon its same as the query I wrote above, however, it will have only one value? How to send array of values because select will fetch many values right?

Comment: @FelixPamittan: Thanks, although it serves the purpose, my lead told me that, what if some failure or some error happens before it sends the updated status ID to Service. In that case, already my update also would have happened which is not correct. So, it is only after ensuring that the update is sent to service and some kind of acknowledgement is received, I should set the status :( I don't know how to do it. But I reckon its same as the query I wrote above, however, it will have only one value? How to send array of values because select will fetch many values right?